# how to append copied values to a new sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a button with a macro assigned to it. The macro needs to take data from certain columns on a worksheet and move them to a new one. This new worksheet should update every time the button is clicked by adding the new values to the existing ones. I am currently using this code:

```
    Sub Consolidate()
'Author:     Jerry Beaucaire'
'Date:       9/15/2009     (2007 compatible)  (updated 4/29/2011)
'Summary:    Merge files in a specific folder into one master sheet (stacked)
'            Moves imported files into another folder
' Edited/altered by me

Dim fName As String, fPath As String, fPathDone As String
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long
Dim wbData As Workbook, wsMaster As Worksheet

'Setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off system messages for now

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BM Condition")    'sheet report is built into

With wsMaster
    If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Clear
        NR = 2
    Else
        NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'appends data to existing data
    End If

'Path and filename (edit this section to suit)
    fPath = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\"            'remember final \ in this string"
    fPathDone = fPath & "Imported\"     'remember final \ in this string
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPathDone                 'creates the completed folder if missing
    On Error GoTo 0
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")        'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired

'Import a sheet from found files
    Do While Len(fName) > 0
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then              'don't reopen this file accidentally
            Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)  'Open file

        'This is the section to customize, replace with your own action code as needed
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Find last row
            Range("P14:S" & LR).EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & NR)
            wbData.Close False                                'close file
            NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1  'Next row
            Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName           'move file to IMPORTED folder
        End If
        fName = Dir                                       'ready next filename
    Loop
End With

ErrorExit:    'Cleanup
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True         'turn system alerts back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True          'turn other macros back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        'refreshes the screen
End Sub
```

This writes to a new workbook, which is fine, but I do not want the original moved to an import folder from its location in the network. I am still experimenting with how to achieve this. Right now I am having errors in the fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")        'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired line. I am not sure why this is and am less sure how to fix it.

Comment: Comment out this line: `Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName`

Comment: (a) "I do not want the original moved to an import folder from its location in the network" - do you mean you want to use the original network path instead of the `"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\"` path you are currently using? 
 If so, change `"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Test\"` to the network path you want to read from.  (b) "I am having errors in the `fName = Dir(fPath & ".xls")` line - if you tell us what errors you are getting, we can possibly help.  (It is very hard to actually get `Dir` to give an error - even non-existent directories don't usually concern it - so this sounds interesting!)

Comment: When i commented out the line Tim told me to the error went away. The program now creates a folder called "TestImported" that is empty.

Comment: What was the error **before** you commented out that line.  (And that folder is now empty because you commented out the line moving the files to the `Imported` sub-folder after they had been processed.)  Actually, on second thoughts, commenting out that line couldn't avoid errors on your `Dir(fpath & "*.xls*")` line, because it is only executed afterwards.

Comment: I changed my fpath value and I think that is what fixed the error. Now i just need to figure out how to get the columns i need from my first sheet into a workbook that can collect and keep record of all data